# What is happening in this C++ constructor?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

In the below [class](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/type-object.html), the member variable `health_` is being initialised with the use of a colon, and before the constructor's main body:

```
class Monster
{
public:
  virtual ~Monster() {}

protected:
  Monster(int startingHealth)
  : health_(startingHealth)
  {}

private:
  int health_; // Current health.
};
```

Why is `health_` not initialised within the constructor's main body like this:

```
class Monster
{
public:
  virtual ~Monster() {}

protected:
  Monster(int startingHealth)
  {
    health_ = startingHealth;
  }

private:
  int health_; // Current health.
};
```

Is the first example different to the second?

Comment: Tip: It's called an initializer list.

Comment: One is *initialization*, the other is *assignment*. The end-result might be the same, but they are semantically very different. For example, try to create a `const` member variable, and try to assign to it... :)